# display hyperlink in php

Tags: php, html, session

I am new to php. Here is a code to check if the user is logged in using session and then allowing the user.

## VALIDATION

```
<?php

session_start();

$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if($uname  == "admin"  &&  $pass == "admin")
{
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
    $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;
    echo "Welcome Mr ".$uname.". You are now logged in ";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='TakeMeHome.html'>Click here to access the application </a>";
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid username or password";
}

?>
```

## Page

```
<?php

session_start();


if($_SESSION['auth'] != 1)
{
    echo "You are not logged in! ";
    echo "<a href = \"TakeMeHome.html\">";
    echo "Access Application";
    echo  "</a>";
    exit();
}

?>

<html>
You are now logged in
</html>
```

But the link tag  is displaying

```
"; echo "Access Application"; echo ""; exit(); } ?>
```

along with the html data. No verification is done. I know there are many better ways to validate user is logged in or not. But i am learning sessions and hence i am using sessions.
Can you please tell me where i am going wrong?
regards.

Comment: I made a habit of using single quotes for echo's and double quotes for the HTML in it. It will work in this case aswell. I guess by putting an extra " after the \" will fix it nonetheless...

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. Usually all the HTML resides in between `<html>` and `</html>`...

Comment: @simone. I dont get it. Which html ? In the last or in the <a> link ?

Answer (score 1):

use single quote in your echo codes like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      echo "<a href='pageToGoTo.html' title='Page to go to' class='whatEver'>Anchor text</a>";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is told already, html should be put in the body...

Comment: But i want to get the session details. And according to W3schools, "Note: The session_start() function must appear BEFORE the <html> tag"

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why @Andy has suggested you put your PHP in your head tags - it isn't javascript. You have 2 ways you can format your PHP and HTML, the first is to put all your PHP above your opening html tag, like so

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['auth'] != 1) {
      $message = 'You are not logged in! <a href="TakeMeHome.html">Access Application</a>';
    } else {
      $message = 'You are logged in!';
    }
?>
<html>
  <head>      
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $message; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or, place it in the body of your page, like so:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
  <head>      
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if($_SESSION['auth'] != 1) {
        echo 'You are not logged in! <a href="TakeMeHome.html">Access Application</a>';
      } else {
        echo 'You are logged in!';
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you are still not getting the desired results then use `var_dump($_SESSION);` to print out your session array and make sure it holds the correct information.